No devices showing up in bluetooth (Lenovo Loq 15IRH8)
I'm running ubuntu 22.04, I was on 24 before and had similar issues where bluetooth didn't see my headphones or any other device but would fix itself after a while for a set amount of time before it came back, I thought it was a stability issue as 24 is quite new so i switched to 22.
Even so the problem got worse, now no device can see my laptop and my laptop cant see any devices either via bluetooth. I tried installing blueman and using that but still nothing. also tried reinstalling bluez and anything of such.

24 and 22 are version numbers of Ubuntu Core not regular Ubuntu is this what you are using? If not please edit the question and state the actual version info.

Can you edit the question to include results from terminal for lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'

Same thing happened to me on Fedora, distrohopped to Ubuntu and Arch but couldn't fix it. Later tested in my seldom used Windows machine, and it turns out bluetooth ain't working there either. It turns out a lot of LOQs have hardware issues when it comes to their motherboard and bluetooth connector. I bought an usb bluetooth adaptor and it started working.
Do not buy LOQ laptops period. They are not as good as the Legion lineup. Lenovo has cost cut in the wrong places. Asus TUF is much more reliable when it comes to linux. And avoid intel in general.

Hey I also face similar issue I was using Arch and everything was working fine but after some times Bluetooth is there but it is not scanning or searching anything
Than i try to install ubuntu here also it is dame than later I found even in windows it is not working
Then luckily I found a solution I think it will help full for someone's else as well
Turn on laptop and keep power button pressed for at least 60 second
After this my Bluetooth start working again
